# Protractor: call a step definition inside another step definition

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I have this step definition that check if an element, identified by a CSS selector, is present in the page:

```
this.Then(/The element with selector "([^"]*)" should be present/, function(elementSelector, callback){
    var selectedElement = element(by.css(elementSelector));

    expect(selectedElement.isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true, "Can't find the element with selector '" + elementSelector + "' that should be present").and.notify(callback);
 });
```

I would like to know if it's possible to call this step definition inside another step definition. This approach could be useful, for example, in a step definition used to fill a text area. In this case I would like to know if the text area exists in page before trying to fill it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for people finding this later...

The creators of Cucumber were [enthusiastic about nesting steps](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2008/11/14/dry-up-your-cucumber-steps/) in the early years, but they [later repented themselves](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/11#issuecomment-9510398) [of ever creating the feature](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/11#issuecomment-4510886), and instead suggest composing functions together.  This is particularly easy to do in javascript, per Aslak's example:

```
function x_is_something(x, cb) {
  console.log('x', x);
  cb();
}

Given(/x is (.*)/, x_is_something);

Given(/super x/, function(cb) {
  x_is_something(97, cb);
});
```

This is why many of the variants of the original Cucumber-Ruby have never supported this feature, and their creators [have even discussed removing it](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2012/04/26/a-vision-for-cucumber-2-0/) from the ones that do.